Are there other Remediation options for AWS Config?
Are there ways to add more Automatic remediations, which are just ssm documents, in aws config? I am referring to remediation for aws config rules. I need to delete certain security groups, I need to add a specific security group to instances. I was not able to find these in the default remediations. Are there also more managed rules I can add as well? I'm currently using a bunch of lambdas to do this so I feel like it gets messy & cluttered. I'm not familiar with ssm documents so any help is appreciated.
